# How I can create a model instance in the same model's schema method?

Tags: node.js, model, mongoose

Subject. I want init a new instance of model in it static method:

```
var Schema = new mongoose.Schema({...});

//...

Schema.statics.createInstance = function (name, pass) {
    var newPerson = new Person; // <--- or 'this', or 'Schema'?
    newPerson.name = name;
    newPerson.pass = pass;
    newPerson.save();
    return newPerson;
}

// ...

module.exports = db.model("Person", Schema);
```

How I can do this?

Comment: So, tnx for response. But most correctly answer will be that:
1. For using statics methods of the model we can using dynamic loading model. `db.model('Person').countComments();`
2. For creating new instance of same model, we need just use `var person = new this;`

Answer (score 28):

You were on the right track; `this` is the Model the schema is registered as within a `schema.statics` method, so your code should change to:

```
Schema.statics.createInstance = function (name, pass) {
    var newPerson = new this();
    newPerson.name = name;
    newPerson.pass = pass;
    newPerson.save();
    return newPerson;
}
```

And Leonid is right about handling the `save` callback, even if it's only to log errors.

Answer (score 1):

You almost answered your question. The only problem with your code is that you don't have a registered model at this point. But you can use `mongoose.model` to fetch it dynamically:

```
Schema.statics.createInstance = function (name, pass) {
    var newPerson = new db.model('Person'); // <- Fetch  model "on the fly"
    newPerson.name = name;
    newPerson.pass = pass;
    newPerson.save();
    return newPerson;
}
```

Ow. And consider handling `save` callback. You can't be sure that `save` operation won't fail.