# save() not working with statics in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Below are various methods i tried to save documents but did not work. what am i doing wrong? Is it the correct way to use static? Is method needed here? If yes how will it be implemented in this situation?

Method 1:

```
userSchema.statics.saveUser = function(data, callback){
   data.save(callback);
};
```

Result - save is not a function

Method 2:

```
userSchema.statics.saveUser = function(data, callback){
   data = new userSchema(data);
   data.save(callback);
};
```

Result - userSchema is not a function

Method 3:

```
userSchema.statics.saveUser = function(data, callback){
   var user = new user(data);
   data.save(callback);
};

var user = Mongoose.model('user', userSchema);
```

Result - user is not a function

**Edit**

Even the below methods does not seem to be working

Method 4:

```
userSchema.statics.saveUser = function(data, callback){
   var user = new this(data);
   user.save(callback);
};
```

Method 5: [JohnnyHK suggested way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14023395/4394926)

```
userSchema.statics.saveUser = function(data, callback){
   var user = new this();
   user.data = data;
   user.save(callback);
};
```

userSchema is like this

```
var db = require('../database');
var Mongoose = db.Mongoose;
require('mongoose-long')(Mongoose);
var SchemaTypes = Mongoose.Schema.Types;

var userSchema = new Mongoose.Schema({
    _id:{ type: String, required: true, unique:true },
    // many fields with type as string and number
    .
    .
    .
    Number:{ type: SchemaTypes.Long, min: 0, default: 0},
});

// query functions here

var user = Mongoose.model('user', userSchema);

// exporting model here
```

Everything works fine if use this.create(data, callback); instead of save but i want to use save for some reasons.

Data before using it for save

```
[ { _id: '2A864493-52614B19',
    name: 'xyz',
    date: 'some date',
    ...
    ...
    ...
    city: 'adf'
} ]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create an instance of your model, because the *save* method is only available for instance.

```
var User = mongoose.model('user', UserSchema);

UserSchema.statics.saveUser = function(data, callback){
    var user = new this(data);
    user.save(callback);
};
```

And please, avoid duplication of variables with adding some uppercase. It's **more readable and less hazardous**.

**Mongoose documentation :** http://mongoosejs.com/docs/models.html

Comment: This gives me a error "Path `_id` is required". If i log user just before saving, the result is null. Meaning after creating an instance data becomes null.

Comment: Can you add your UserSchema to the post please ?

Comment: Yeah sure added one. Please check.

Comment: Hmmm ... _id field is required, and you're error message is saying than you don't give it. Add a user._id value, or remove the field from database and let mongoose generate it automatically.

Comment: i am providing id, data has unique id provided by me but after creating instance like you said, data becomes null. why? Also like i said everything works fine if i use create() instead of save(). And you can create your own value for _id field in mongo.

Comment: Just taking your words, i tried the same thing with my other model where _id is auto generated their i got an error saying data.save is not a function meaning it is not able to create a instance of the model.

Comment: Can you add a console.log(data); before using it and post the result ?

Comment: Yes i added the data. Please check.

Comment: Okay. Your data is an array. So you need to do : var user = new this(data[0]);

Comment: You are right. That was the problem. But data is a array of multiple objects so what to do for that?

Comment: Make a loop, create a new document for each data in your array, and save each document. That's the classic way to save multiple documents in mongoose.

Comment: Thanks for helping me :)

Comment: Hi. I am almost following your approach. But my data doesn't seem to get saved into the database.  Can you help out with that?

Comment: @node_saini Even I am facing the same problem. But none of the things seems to work for me. Can you please help me out?